# network: destination host unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I am using Linux oess (CentOS). I am working on a VM:
[image]

In the terminal, I'm trying to:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

to see my connectivity. It says:

```
Network is unreachable
```

Then I typed:

```
ifconfig: 
  inet addr: 192.168.56.101
```

Then:

```
sudo /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 gw 192.168.56.101 eth0
```

Now I'm doing the same ping and it says:

```
Destination host is unreachable
```

for all the sequences.

What is the source of the problem?

route output:
[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28798/discussion-between-ray-bsd-and-zeev1079).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First things first: can you ping 192.168.56.1? If so, then you have an IP connection to the router. Set this as your default route. Otherwise try pinging 192.168.56.255 (broadcast) to see on what address you might get
replies. See arp -a to check what addresses you can find.

Can you ping 8.8.4.4 (google) after changing the default route? If so,you have internet access. If not, check the router.

Can you ping [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)? If not, you might have a DNS problem.

Do you get results from nslookup [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)?

Comment: yes i can ping 192.168.56.101. for 8.8.4.4 i can not reach the destination host. so the problem is internet access. Regarding my router, i still believe it's not a router problems since i usually use diffrent routers. and it did not work in any of them

Comment: yes its not a router problem..it the config of your eth0 network settings.

Comment: Yea, i knew it. but how do solve this issue. im truly do not know my direction

Comment: try 
#dhclient -r eth0

Or
$sudo dhclient -r eth0

This will try to get a automatic ip address from your router.

Comment: I did not get any adress, please expand your answer

Comment: try to delete your default gw of your machine. #route del default gw .

And then try to ping 192.168.56.1 or 192.168.56.254.

If ull get a reply from one of the ips..this should be your default gw then. (Router IP)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28796/discussion-between-ray-bsd-and-zeev1079).

Answer (score 14):

try DHCP for the network interface

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart && sudo dhclient
```

Comment: You're a life saver. In my case it's network-manager and not networking.

Answer (score 3):

check the network card of the VM in the virtualization software. is it in "bridged" mode? or in a "NAT" or "host-only" mode?

in the last case change it to bridged and try $sudo dhclient

in the first case, see if the hypervisor itself can ping to its default gw and 8.8.4.4

Comment: no i can not ping my ip and not 8.8.4.4

Answer (score 2):

There are two cases what a computer can do, when it has to forward an IP package:

- **First case:** Say the destination IP of the incoming package is
  `10.20.30.40` and the interface on which the package arrives is configured to be `10.20.30.1 netmask 255.255.255.0`. This is, the
  packages destination subnet and the interfaces subnet are the same.
  Then your OS will forward the package to the broadcast `10.20.30.255`
  (it says "Here is a package that is addressed for someone in my own
  hood, so please take it!").
- **Second case:** Say the destination IP of the incoming package is
    `10.20.40.40` and the interface on which the package arrives is configured to be `10.20.30.1 netmask 255.255.255.0`. Then the
  destination address lies outside of the interfaces subnet. So it does
  not know where to send it. So it forwards it to the default gateway
  which in turn tries to find the destination.

In your case the default gateway is exactly the same as your interface IP. That means: When your computer does not know where to send a package it sends it to itself respectively to one of its own interfaces. That sounds strange - and it is. An interface gateway should be in the same subnet as the interface itself, but it should never BE itself. You need another default gateway in the same subnet to be happy.

If you don't know your default gateway for this interface, so try to get a valid default gateway for this interface via DHCP configuration (configure this interface to be a DHCP client).

UPDATE:

In the case you are working in a VM (I see it is Virtual Box) try to find out the IP address of the "Virtual Box Host Only Adapter" on your host machine (command: ifconfig or ipconfig). Then configure the IP address of the VM host only adapter to be the default gateway of your VM guest.

UPDATE2:

On your host machine your should activate ipv4-forwarding and NAT to get internet access:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <interface on which you have the i-net access> -j MASQUERADE
```

UPDATE3:

If your want to use the "Host Only Adapter" then it may be possible, that you first have to create an "Host Only Network" under File->Preferences choosing the tab "Host Only Networks"...

Comment: Im working on a VM, it's maybe the reason why i m little confused with your answers.

Comment: I allready did what you said, but it's stil does not work properly, i changed it to bridge adapter

Comment: in your network settings inside virtual box: what is when you switch your "Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop" adapter type to "Intel PRO/1000 T Server" ???

Comment: i can not touch it,  im so lost with this issue, i think it's a lost case. the reason i doing ping is because i can not do wget to downlad some webpage

Comment: what is the interface you getting internet to? Inside Vbox switch to bridge mode and use exactly the interface you getting internet connection to. Then switch the adapter type to "Intel PRO/1000 T Server" - it MUST work as far as your LAN provides an dhcp service. Can your post your /etc/network/interfaces file on the guest?

Answer (score 1):

Check your hw_address and add it to your DNS IP address:

```
$ arp -n 
$ arp -s <ip_address> <hw_address>
```

**NOTE:** hw_address is your MAC address

Answer (score 0):

*(I cannot comment yet, hence a reply)*

A **[router](http://pc.net/helpcenter/answers/difference_between_router_and_modem)** is a box that is separate from your computer. Where does the network cable from your computer go to? That might be your router. Can you post the name and identification numbers of that box? It might help us in assisting you.

My guess is that your router has the address 192.168.56.1 (if not, try 192.168.56.255) but that need not be true. See if you can ping it, and if you can open your router's configuration page if you go to that IP address in a web browser.

If so, set that IP address as your gateway. The command you posted seems correct.

Comment: Im working on a VM, it's maybe the reason why i was little confused with your answers

Comment: This is Q&A site, not a forum, please be so polite to read the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and to apply the part about not including chit-chat in your posts

Answer (score 0):

Your Virtual Box network adapter is set to "[Host-only](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly)".

Host-only networking allows your guest to access your host and your guest to access other guests. However, it does not allow network traffic to pass between the guest to the real physical network beyond the host, including the internet.

You are unable to ping 8.8.8.8 because that machine is neither your host nor one of your virtual machines. Change your Virtual Box network type to "NAT" or "Bridged" if you require access to the outside world.